# Universal Links don't redirect the user to my app when tapped

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I implemented [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in my app, and it works like charm.
But after the `iOS` 9.2 Update it stopped working.

When the app is already installed, and I tap on the link which in iOS9.1 open my app, in iOS9.2 it isn't.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was an old format for the `apple-app-site-association`.

The **old** format was:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": {
            "1234ABCDE.com.app.myapp": {
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update the format fixed the problem, and the **new** format is:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234ABCDE.com.app.myapp",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can check if the format is right here:
https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/
If it says: recommended - old format, so it won't work on `iOS9.2`, So update to the new format.

Hope it help someone.

Comment: Is this mentioned in any official release notes?

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue introduced with iOS 9.2.  Please see https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links for a full description of the issue.

TLDR - It's not known if this was intentional or a bug on Apple's part.  What is known is that with the update to iOS 9.2, the model dialog which was previously used to prompt the user to open the app (associated with the URL scheme) is no longer modal.  This means that javascript execution continues and if you were previously counting on the modal dialog to prevent redirecting the user to the app store, that no longer works.  The end user experience for most apps using URL schemes is that they are ALWAYS redirected to the app store where the button says "open" instead of "get" for the app.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Universal Links but only with deep links that use custom URL schemes...